# AD Permissions with a new user account

Tags: powershell

Have a script for creating new user accounts, including a home directory.  The account setup works fine, but when I try to assign the permission on the home directory it gets an error on the Set-ACL command, specifying that the user cannot be found.  We do have multiple Domain Controllers, so I can understand how one DC is hit on user creation but another when I try to pull perms, however at the top of the script I use "Set-ADServerSettings -PreferredServer " to specify which DC to talk to.  I was expecting this to solve the issue, but no joy.

The script is too large to post here, but the flow is as follows:
* Load AD module
* Parse CSV file for user info
* Create user account
* Create home directory on server hosting home folders
* Set perms on directory -error

The code fragment for setting the perms is:

```
# get current permissions of the newly created home folder
$acl = Get-Acl $newHomeFolder
# allow inherited rules from parent folder
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($False, $True)

$newAcl = "<domain>\$logonName", "FullControl", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow"
$objNewAcl = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($newAcl)
$acl.AddAccessRule($objNewAcl)

Set-Acl -Path $newHomeFolder -AclObject $acl
```

Any thoughts on how I can get this resolved an allow the permission to be set?

Comment: Does it work if you wait and run it after allowing for replication between the DCs?  Just confirming it's purely a timing issue and not something else. I've had similar issues creating groups and setting ACL's within the same script. I've resolved it by throwing in a start-sleep for 20 seconds or so. Not sure if that's practical given the number of users you're processing at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar thing I was working on for a school. After many  trials and many errors, I came to this:

```
$acl = Get-Acl $newHomeFolder
$inherit = [system.security.accesscontrol.InheritanceFlags]"ObjectInherit",[system.security.accesscontrol.InheritanceFlags]"ContainerInherit"
$propagation = [system.security.accesscontrol.PropagationFlags]"None"
$accessrule = New-Object system.security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("[domain\$username", "FullControl", $inherit, $propagation, "Allow")
$acl.AddAccessRule($accessrule)
set-acl -aclobject $acl $directory
```

Hope this helps.